# input field error with php echo statement

Tags: php, forms, echo, field

I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''05/12/13)' at line 2
```

Because of this code:

```
<input type="text" name="submitdate" value="<?php echo date('d/m/y'); ?>" readonly>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That error message is from MySQL, not PHP - could you add the code where you're trying to add it to the database, as well as the table structure?

Comment: Without seeing your query, my guess is that MySQL is expecting a date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" rather than "d/m/y".

Comment: Can you post your mysql query and table structure ?

Comment: I have sorted it guys, thanks @showdev.
MySQL only accepts that format.

Anyone can help me out for php echo date format?

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects dates to be formatted like "YYYY-MM-DD" rather than "d/m/y".

This will format the date appropriately:

```
date('Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php